# ng-repeat not affected by clearing array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

In html I'm repeating over an array of strings:

```
<div class="palette__record"
     data-ng-repeat="n in palette track by $index"
     data-ng-style="{'background-color':'#'+n}">
</div>
```

In controller `palette` is gathered from localForage (same as localstorage but async)

```
$localForage.getItem('palette')
    .then(colors => {
        if(colors) vm.palette = colors;
    });
```

This works fine, now after click button I'm "clearing" palette by seting it to `[]` in localForage then geting it again and seting value in controller:

```
vm.clearEntirePalette = () => {
    $localForage.setItem('palette', [])
        .then(() => {
            $localForage.getItem('palette')
                .then(colors => {
                    console.log('clear palette', colors);
                    if(colors) {
                        vm.palette = colors;
                    } else {
                        vm.palette = [];
                    }
                });
        });
};
```

Here as you can see I'm console loging to double check and it's fine it's empty array. Now since I always want my array to contain 8 elements (also when other operations on this array) I have $watch which is invoked **after** `vm.palette = colors;` from above.

```
vm.$watch('palette', newVal => {
    console.log('caught change');

    if(newVal.length < 8) {
        const fillArr =  new Array(8 - newVal.length);
        fillArr.fill('');
        vm.palette = vm.palette.concat(fillArr);
        console.log('after fill', vm.palette)
        //$scope.$apply();
    }
}, true);
```

This also works fine, after above code palette is array with 8 empty strings. However `ng-repeat` does not catch this change and doesn't update. I tried to use `$scope.$apply()` in `$watch` after fill but it cause error

> [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

How to fix it so ng-repeat reflect array?

Comment: I don't really know however localforage have its core and its lib for angularjs and I'm using angular-localforage lib so I would bet that it's angularJS promise whatever it is. I'm not certain tho. Can I check it somehow?

Comment: This is open source so you can clone and run it on your machine https://github.com/d0peCode/colorReader

Comment: track by $index << this might be cause, just remove it (It makes no sense on string array anyway)

Comment: What do you mean it make perfect sense because I have empty elements which are same - `""`

Comment: Try to run digest cycle using $applyAsync() in clearEntirePalette function

Comment: IMO I see couple of mistakes here. First is, you're modifying palette inside $watch which will again invoke the same $watch. Secondly, vm.palette = vm.palette.concat(fillArr); Since you've already done concat, vm.palette already got fillArr. You don't need to assign this again to vm.palette.